# Viewing a file over a network: meaning of ~@k

Tags: vim

I have `showcmd` set, and often when viewing (NOT editing) a file over a network, I observe the characters `~@k` appearing in the showcmd position. This only happens when I move the cursor, and the cursor movement is visibly slow. I can overcome this using `set eventignore=CursorMoved`, so I assume the network file is being read while updating the foldtext, statusline or matching parentheses.

I am not sure why the file needs to be accessed so often (if indeed that is the case). Is there any way of disabling this behaviour without losing the CursorMoved actions?

It's a shame that a web search for `~@k` is not possible!

Comment: +1; I've idly wondered this myself in former years. Haven't seen it for some years, though, purely because it's too fast now.

Comment: I'm seeing it more often than I used to, but that may be because I made some modifications to the statusline and foldtext which might be slowing this down. I shall investigate.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Are you using your arrow keys to move the cursor? From Vim's repeat.txt documentation:

> The first character of a key code is 0x80 or 128, shown on the screen as "~@".  The second one can be found in the list |key-notation|.

I'm guessing the 'k' is for key/keypad? If I scroll using my arrow keys, I see "~@k" in the showcmd field. If I scroll using hjkl, I see hjkl.

Comment: Yes, I was using the arrow keys, so that makes perfect sense. Thanks for your answer.